# Java/JNI - Is it possible to retrieve the native function address from the Java "side"?

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface, native

When calling from native code (i.e. c/c++) to a Java function through JNI, is it possible to get the native function address when inside the Java function?

I assume not, but maybe some JNI experts can prove me wrong...

btw: I'm working on Android, I have no control on the native function.

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard if you allow for a native call to get the address - just have the native call return a `jlong`:  `return( ( jlong ) &some_jni_function_name );`.  I have no idea what you could **do** with it, but it's possible.  From pure Java?  Probably not, but someone may have a way to do it.

Comment: As I said I don't have any control on the native part.

Comment: Does that preclude you from writing your own JNI code?  You'd probably have to use `dlsym()` to get the address in that case instead of trying to find the address directly.

Comment: I can't use `dlsym` because the symbol is hidden. I thought there might be another way of getting the function's address.